# Javascript dialog box with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm trying to recreate the same dialog box on my sign up page but it does not seem to want to pop up.

Here's my coffeescript:

```
$('#dummy_addresses_dialog').dialog
    autoOpen: false
    width: 940
    modal: true
    # close: (event, ui) ->
    #   $("#pm_assignment_form")[0].reset()
    buttons: 
      'Cancel': -> $(@).dialog('close')

$("#dummy_address_dialog_link").live 'click', ->
    $('#dummy_addresses_dialog').dialog('open')
    false
```

Here's my link:

```
= link_to "*", "#", :id => "dummy_address_dialog_link"
```

This is my index.html.haml where I'm serving up my partial:

```
#dummy_addresses_dialog{:title => "Dummy Addresses", :style => "display:none;"}
  = render "dummy_addresses_table"
```

but when I try to copy the link and add it to my sign up page the popup does not appear it works fine on my other page though.

Is there something I'm not copying over to make this work?

Comment: how would i add in the script to launch the dialogue box when i click on the link?